# Taking $y \rightarrow 0$ without continuity

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Find all functions $f: \mathbb{R}^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ such that
$$f(xf(x + y)) = yf(x) + 1$$
holds for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$.

Can I take $y \rightarrow 0$, and solve the functional equation $$f(xf(x))=1$$

Without proving that $f$ is continuous? Since taking $y \rightarrow 0$ does not affect the domain directly, is it possible? If not, why?

Comment: In short, you cannot.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: If your $\mathbb R^+$ is the set of reals $>0,$ you cannot (if you believe you can, expose to us your thoughts and we shall point the mistake). And if your $\mathbb R^+$ is the set of reals $\ge0,$ you don't need any limit (just evaluate your equation at $x=0$).

Comment: $f(x)=1$ is one of solutions to $f(xf(x))=1$, but it doesn't satisfy the original equation as it becomes $1 = y + 1, \forall y>0$.

Comment: Can I stil take $y \rightarrow 0$ if I have proven $f$ is continous? The constant function  case is can be eliminated easily hence $xf(x)$ should be constant,  which gives $f(x) = \frac{c}{x}$ for come constant c

Comment: $f(x)=\frac c x$ $(c>0)$ is one solution to $f(xf(x))=1$. However, only $c=1$ meets the original equation. Are you claiming that the solutions to the 2nd eq. are the superset of the solutions to the original eq.? If that can be guaranteed, then it makes some sense to find all the solutions for the 2nd eq. and cherry pick those that satisfy the original eq. But, how can you guarantee that there's no case where there exists a solution to the original equation that is not a solution to the 2nd equation? Rather, it is likely to be the other way as the 2nd eq. was based on more restricted condition

Comment: You cannot use a hypothesis you do not have. If the statement of the problem does not mention continuity then you cannot use it.